# Pass parameter to iframe src

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, iframe

I have a webpage that contains an embedded page using an iframe. I have parsed the URL to append the parameter to the main url to create a new link, but now I need to pass the path to the iframe src to load the page when the link is clicked on.

#### iframe code

```
<iframe name= "myiframe" id = "load" src="https://www.site-name.com/Manual/application.htm">
```

#### jQuery code to parse url

```
  $(document).ready(function () {
var URL = 'https://www.site-name.com/f1'; // MAIN 

var otherURL = 'https://www.site-name.com/Manual/module_1_4_2.htm'; // iframe URL

//Create a new link with the url as its href:
var a = $('<a>', {
    href: otherURL
});
var sResult = '<b>Protocol:</b> ' + a.prop('protocol') + '<br/>'  + '<b>Host name: </b>' + a.prop('hostname') + '<br/>' + '<b>Path: </b>' + a.prop('pathname') + '<br/>' 

var path = a.prop('pathname');   // pass the path to the MAIN URL 
var newURL = URL + "?page="+ path.substring(path.lastIndexOf('/') + 1);

// display new URL 
$('span').html(sResult + "<br><b>New URL: </b>" + newURL);  

// Correctly displays
// New URL:https://www.site-name.com/f1? page=module_1_4_2.htm
```

The new url is now `https://www.site-name.com/f1?page=module_1_5_3.htm`

This works but now I need to pass the query path to the iframe src to load the page when the link is clicked.

What I am trying to do is pass the path to the iframe src.
How do I pass the path variable to the iframe src.

Answer (score 1):

Use jQuerys function [`load()`](http://api.jquery.com/load/) to change the `src` attribute of your iframe.

```js
var url = $("#load").attr ('src');

var a = $('#link');
var path = a.prop ('pathname');
var redirectUrl = url + "?page="+ path.substring (path.lastIndexOf ('/') + 1);

$('#load').load (redirectUrl);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<iframe name="myiframe" id="load" src="https://www.site-name.com/f1"></iframe>
<br/>
<a id="link" href="https://www.site-name.com/f1?page=module_1_5_3.htm" target="myiframe">TEST LINK</a>
```

Comment: Thank you, I've tried it and it doesn't seem to work. The goal is to have the Test Url reload the new page in the iframe.

Comment: @pfiguer1 I updated my answer. Hope things get a little bit clearer now.

Comment: I understand how this works but what i need is to pass the query path to the the src, and what you provided above doesn't do that.

Comment: @pfiguer1 by setting a `target` attribute you are passing whatever is in `href` to your iframe as `src`. and `href` is set dynamically by jquery. sorry but i dont get what you want to achieve.

Comment: To clarify, what I am trying to do is pass this `?page=module_1_5_3.htm` to the iframe src. Thank you

Comment: @pfiguer1 ah ok, sorry i misunderstood. i edited my answer again.

Comment: @pfiguer1 no this needs to be on the page with the link and iframe.

Comment: @pfiguer1 did it work in the end? if so, please accept my answer. thank you.